# fseek and fwrite past EOF

Tags: c, file, file-io, binary

Let us first assume I have a 20 byte binary file consisting of 5 integers. Now let us say that I tried to:

```
fseek(fp, 2*sizeof(int), SEEK_END)
```

and I tried to call:

```
fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
```

Is this even possible?

If it is possible will the new binary file be of size 32 or will it simply be of size 24? If is it of 32, what is the content of the binary file from position 20 to 27?

Comment: Suggest `fseek (fp, 7*sizeof(int), SEEK_BEGIN)` to avoid "A binary stream need not meaningfully support fseek calls
with a whence value of SEEK_END."

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/):

> - Library implementations are allowed to not meaningfully support `SEEK_END` (**therefore, code using it has no real standard portability**).

And [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek):

> **POSIX allows seeking beyond the existing end of file**. If an output is
>   performed after this seek, any read from the gap will return zero
>   bytes. Where supported by the filesystem, this creates a **sparse file**.

On a my testsystem `seeking` past `SEEK_END` fills the remainder of the file with nullbytes upto the new file pointer.

Comment: Does this mean it is not possible to call fseek(fp, 2*sizeof(int), SEEK_END) but it is possible to call fseek(fp, 7*sizeof(int), SEEK_SET). And if I try to call fwrite at that position the new file size would simply be 24, I dont really understand what is meant by a sparse file.

Comment: @Janjan It depends on whether the system supports it or not, so the code would not really be portable.

Comment: @Janjan A **sparse file** will only write blocks containing data to disk (mostly 16kB blocks) and 'fill' the rest with \0. For example if you have a file with 100 bytes at the beginning and 100 bytes at around 1GB you'll have a 1GB file that will only occupy 32kB on disk (the part not on disk being all zeros).

Comment: If I try to access this file using fread must I use the same pointer position in which I used to call fwrite?

Comment: @Janjan Yes, the OS takes care of all that (from the code there is no difference if the data is on disk or are virtual zeros). If you later write at around 500MB a new 16kB block (or 2) will be written to disk. The only drawback is that those blocks will then not be 'in order' on disk and it could take slightly longer to read if you later fill all those empty blocks (just like a defragmented file).

Comment: The 16kB blocksize mentioned above is on Windows, Linux may be using different blocksizes but the idea is the same.

Comment: However the actual file size is the numbet of bytes written, right? Regardless of the \0 in between?

Comment: @Janjan The file size would be 1GB, the space occupied on disk would be 32kB in the above example. This can be important on systems where users have restrictions on disk space - usually the 1GB will be counted in this case.

Comment: Oh so some files that I usually see where the actual size and the size on disk are different are actually sparse files?

Comment: @Janjan Files are written to clusters (multiple sectors) on disk. Those clusters are usually 4kB and the size on disk for a file is always a multiple of that. So if the difference is smaller than 4kB this is the reason and those are not sparse files.